# OU process generator

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

Consider the centered OU process given by $X(t)=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}e^{-\alpha t}B(e^{2\alpha t})$ where $(B(t))_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. It is obvious why this is a 0 mean process with covariance $\frac{\beta^2}{2\alpha} e^{-\alpha|t-s|}$ for all $s,t\ge 0$. I am trying to see why this is a Markov process and what it's generator process is? every reference just states this is a fact.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a typo. Looking at [temporarily homogeneous OU process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Properties_of_sample_paths) should it not be
$$
X(t)=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}e^{-\alpha t}B(e^{2\alpha t})\,?
$$
Another way of writing $X(t)$ is
$$
X(t)=X(0)+\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}e^{-\alpha t}\int_0^te^{\alpha s}\,dW(s)
$$
where $W$ is another standard Brownian motion.
Switching to the process
$$
Y(t)=X(t)-X(0)=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}e^{-\alpha t}\int_0^te^{\alpha s}\,dW(s)
$$
Ito's formula yields the Langevin SDE
\begin{align}
dY(t)&=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}\,\left\{dW(t)+\int_0^te^{\alpha s}\,dW(s)\,d(e^{-\alpha t})\right\}\\
&=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}\,\left\{dW(t)-\alpha\,e^{-\alpha t}\int_0^te^{\alpha s}\,dW(s)\,dt\right\}\\
&=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}\,dW(t)-\alpha Y(t)\,dt\,.\tag{1}
\end{align}
This shows that the **generator** of the Markov process $Y(t)$ is the differential operator
$$\tag{2}
\boxed{\frac{\beta^2}{4\alpha}\frac{d^2}{dy^2}-\alpha\frac{d}{dy}\,.}
$$
**Side Remarks**: The variance of $X(t)$ is the constant $\beta^2/(2\alpha)\,.$ The variance of $Y(t)$ is
$$
\frac{\beta^2}{2\alpha}e^{-2\alpha t}\int_0^te^{2\alpha s}\,ds=\beta^2\frac{1-e^{-2\alpha t}}{4\alpha^2}\,.
$$
The expectation of $Y(t)$ is zero. The solution of (1) that starts at $Y_0\not=0$ has expectation $Y_0e^{-\alpha t}$ which tends to zero as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Fixed comment thank you. So I do have a few questions. Why do we even need to work with Y_t? I assume it is to derive the Langevin SDE (I am vaguely familiar with this). From this SDE you immediately get that Y_t is markovian and also get the generator? Furthermore why is this the same generator as the one for X_t?

Comment: $X(t)$ starts at the random variable $\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}B(1)$ whilst $Y(t)$ starts at zero. Strictly speaking: to have a Markov process and to be able to speak about its generator we have to allow the process to start at an arbitrary point. The standard relationship between Markovian SDEs and the infinitesimal generators is explained for example in the book *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* by Karatzas & Shreve.

Comment: Sorry why does the starting point condition matter? The definition of a Markov process does not consider what the starting point is at all. furthermore the time homogeneity condition also does not require this.

Comment: @247 : I am running out of ideas how to express this. Your question why we need to work with $Y(t)$ seems totally secondary in light of the fact that it differs from $X(t)$ only by the starting value. "The definition of Markov process does not consider what the starting point is at all." I agree if that means that the Markov process has to be able to start at *any* given point.

Comment: Well you claim that since $X(0)$ is random variable, then we cannot talk about the process $X$ being Markov. I just wanted to know why that is. This is ultimately the reason why we work with $Y$ in the first place. 

I think this is because you are using a result pertaining to SDEs-Markov processes (which then may require more conditions than just the definition of a Markov process). 

Do you know how I would do this without appealing to SDEs? The reason why I ask is because $X_t$ is explicitly given as a function of a Brownian motion. I think there should be a cleaner way to get this.